# Saving data to a file and retrieving it w.r.t. user id

Tags: java

I'm developing an application using Java Swing. I want to save the details entered by the user in a file (and not in a database) in such a way that I should later be able to retrieve all data related to a specific id. How should I do this?

The user details I need are: ID, Name, Address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **How should i go for it?? The user details i may ask is : ID, Name, address. Thanks ! in advance**

There are several options.

- CSV

  Probably the simples approach. You could implement this using for instance [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/). As long as you escape special characters properly, you could do away with one person per line.
- XML

  There are many XML libraries readily available for Java. Very flexible, but perhaps an overkill for your application, since you're not really serializing a tree-like structure.
- Java Properties files

  Exist in the standard API. Have built in save/load facilities. Drawback would probably be that you would need an ad-hoc solution for multiple persons.

Comment: Yet. OpenCSV will work fine with eclipse. (That's what I used when writing OpenCSV code :-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe HSQL DB is something for you. You get a full fletched JDBC compatible DB which consists of one jar an stores everything into a single file.

http://hsqldb.org/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an object database, or Java serialization. Java serialization would give you an object graph, simply and easily; if you're using a data structure already and you're satisfied with it, serialization is easy and convenient. If you're not using a data structure already or you need more capabilities, an object database might be the way to go.

Consider db4o (http://db4o.com); it's very fast, very light, and very capable.